# Is sizeof(void()) a legal expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, sizeof, void

From [[5.3.3/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1), I found that:

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type

From [[3.9/5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#5) I found that:

> Incompletely-defined object types and cv void are incomplete types

Anyway, for `sizeof` does not evaluate it's operands, I would have said that `sizeof(void())` was a legal expression (actually GCC compiles it and the result is 1).
On the other side, from [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof), `void` is not mentioned while discussing `sizeof`, neither when the types having size 1 are mentioned, nor in the list of the ones having an *implementation defined* size.

The question is thus: is `sizeof(void())` a legal expression?
Is it guaranteed to have size equal to 1?
Or is it a legal expression resulting in an UB and that's all?

Comment: [CppReference sizeof operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) says it is an error

Comment: I don't think there's anything special about `void()` here - you get the same result for `sizeof(int(int,float))` in GCC.

Comment: GCC used to have (and probably still has) extension where `sizeof(void) == 1`

Comment: `sizeof(void)` must be a g++ extension. I get a warning when compiled with `-Wall`.

Comment: My copy of g++ says this: `warning: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to a function type [-Wpointer-arith]`

Comment: what version and switches of gcc did you find compiled `sizeof(void())` ?

Comment: @M.M Uhm, I tried it on a mobile app (C4Droid) and I cannot say what's the underlying compiler. Anyway, it accepts `-std=c1z`, so quite a recent one I'd say.

Comment: maybe the app suppresses error/warning messages

Comment: @M.M Of course, after someone pointed the warnings out, I've found that it suppresses them. My fault. Anyway I'd leave the question opened for it looks interesting after all.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I made a mistake by mixing up the question. Closed the other question as duplicate of this one.

Comment: @BЈовић Probably also the other question should be reopened. They are somehow different. My two cents. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @skypjack The answers are the same - therefore no.

Comment: void() is just function

Comment: A downvote one year later with no explanation is quite interesting indeed.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`void()` is a function type (it's a function which takes no arguments and returns nothing), so it's not a valid type in `sizeof()`.

Comment: Isn't it interpreted as in `decltype(void())` (note that it is not a function type in this case)? I would have said it indeed. Why do they differ?

Comment: @skypjack When you use a function type with `decltype` it gives the type of the return-type. In the case of `void()` the return type is `void` so that's the type of `decltype(void())`.

Comment: So why `decltype(void(void))` doesn't work, as well as `decltype(int(int))`? No, it is not a function type when using`decltype`. In the case of `sizeof` I cannot say.

Comment: @skypjack I think I figured it out now, `decltype` needs an *expression*, and not a type. `void()` is not actually a type here, but an expression, a C-style cast (just like e.g. `int(12.34)`) `void(void)` is not an expression therefore it doesn't work. How the compiler parses different things depends on the context, when it expects a type it parses as a type, when it expects an expression it parses as an expression.  `sizeof()` (with the parentheses) expects first of all a type, otherwise it's parsed as a parenthesized expression.

Comment: [cppreference sizeof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) provides an example usage of `sizeof` opeartor, and it clearly says **size of function** to `sizeof(void())`, and says, it's an error, here, `// cout << "size of function: " << sizeof(void()) << '\n'; // error`, i think it's really a function type.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I would create a question for this and accept this exact answer, so as to let it for future readers. What do you think? It's an interesting answer in the answer indeed.

Comment: @skypjack You can always copy my comment into an answer for such a question if you'd like. (As long as you give me some credit... ;) )

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [That's it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279074/what-does-the-void-in-decltypevoid-means-exactly/39279075#39279075). No reputation or credits wanted, just an interesting answer in the answer that is worth to be discussed apart. Let's see what the language-lawyers will say about that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: *"When you use a function type with `decltype` it gives the type of the return-type."*... I'm not convinced. Are you saying the argument which is passed to `decltype` is a *type*, not a *value*?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So, `sizeof((void()))` considers `void()` the same way `decltype` does, right?

Comment: @skypjack Yes, `(void())` is an expression.

Answer (score 39):

From looking at [**CppReference.com - sizeof operator**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof), the documentation literally states:

> `sizeof` cannot be used with **function types**, incomplete types, or
>   bit-field glvalues.

And since `void()` is a function type, then `sizeof(void())` is not a legal expression.

In their usage example, we can see their **error** comment on this line:

```
std::cout << "size of function: " << sizeof(void()) << '\n'; // error
```

Answer (score 8):

Also, if you compile the code, such as the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << sizeof(void());
}
```

The code compiles correctly and produces a value of 1, but if you look at the compilation, you see this:

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> main.cpp:5:29: warning: invalid application of 'sizeof' to a function type [-Wpointer-arith]
>
> std::cout << sizeof(void());

So, it is evident that `sizeof()` doesn't apply for function types, so the code produces a warning. It is invalid.

---

[Code here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8f2fe4fe8bc9ab1)

---

Answer (score 6):

A little premise.

The question arose from a misinterpretation of the `sizeof` operator.
In fact the OP considered `void()` an expression that has incomplete type in the context of `sizeof` and the question itself can be read as - *why `sizeof` accept the expression `void()`, that is an incomplete type and should not be accepted as mentioned in the working draft*?
That's why [3.9/5] is mentioned actually, otherwise it wouldn't have made sense.

That said, the fact is that the question contains actually two interesting questions:

- Why is `sizeof(void())` not legal?
  This is the actual question as from the title itself.
- Why is `sizeof((void()))` not legal?
  This is the intended question of the OP.

Answers below:

- `void()` in `sizeof(void())` is interpreted as a function type and it is ill-formed as for [[5.3.3/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1) (emphasis mine):

  > **The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function** or incomplete **type, to the parenthesized name of such types**, [...]
- `(void())` in `sizeof((void()))` is an expression that has incomplete type `void` (note that `sizeof` is an unevaluated context) and it is ill-formed as for [[5.3.3/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1) (emphasis mine):

  > **The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has** function or **incomplete type**, to the parenthesized name of such types, [...]

In both cases GCC compiles the code with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

As already highlighted in the docs here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

**Notes**

`sizeof()` cannot be used with **function types**, incomplete types, or bit-field glvalues.

Since `void()` is a function type, so its not a valid type of `sizeof()`

Note:

`void()` is a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing

Quoting a Example from Docs:

```
//<< "size of function: " << sizeof(void()) << '\n'  // error
```

So Answers to your questions:

1)No it is not a legal Expression.

2)It will show as 1 , but will show a warning

3)same as 1).

Comment: 2) It does compile though, this was stated in the original question

Answer (score 1):

Straigth from the C99 reference NO

Stated in the document under section **6.5.3.4  The sizeof operator**:

> The sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function type or an incomplete  type, to the parenthesized name of such a type, or to an expression  that designates a bit-field member.

According to item 19 and 20 of section **6.2.5 Types**:

> 19. The void type comprises an empty set of values; **it is an incomplete type** that cannot be completed.
> 20. ...A function type describes a function with specified return type. A function type is characterized by its return type and the number and  types of its parameters.
>       A function type is said to be derived from its return type, and if its return type is T, the function type is sometimes called ‘‘function  returning T’’. The construction of a function type from a return type is called ‘‘function type derivation’’.

**Thus void() is a function type derived from an incomplete type and its illegal as operand for the sizeof. That said its returns will depends on the compiler implementation and does not have any return value guaranteed**

[C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: See the tags of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, however there is no difference in the definition of void type in the section 3.9.1 item 9 of current C++ standard and regarding the sizeof operator in section 5.3.3 item 1: The
sizeof operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type... [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf]

Comment: Absolutely, but for the question is tagged C++, it's worth mentioning the right reference. That's all.