# Is sizeof(int()) a legal expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, grammar

This question is inspired by [Is sizeof(void()) a legal expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278200/is-sizeofvoid-a-legal-expression) but with an important difference as explained below.

The expression in question is:

```
sizeof( int() )
```

In the C++ grammar there appears:

> *unary-expression:*
>
> - `sizeof` *unary-expression*
> - `sizeof (` *type-id* `)`

however, `( int() )` can match both of these cases with different meanings:

- As a *unary-expression*, it is a value-initialized `int` prvalue, surrounded in redundant parentheses
- As a *type-id*, it is the type of a function with no parameters returning `int`.

In the semantic constraints for `sizeof`, i.e. C++14 [expr.sizeof]/1, it explains that the form `sizeof(` *type-id* `)` may not be applied to a function type.

However I'm not sure whether the violation of that semantic constraint implies that `sizeof( int() )` is correct and uses the `sizeof` *unary-expression* form; or whether there is some other rule that disambiguates the two cases at an earlier stage of grammar matching.

NB. For the other question `sizeof(void())`, neither interpretation is valid, so it could be argued that the compiler is correct to reject the expression with an error message indicating it matched the *type-id* form. However, gcc rejects `sizeof( int() )` with a message about *type-id*.

To be clear, my question is: "Is `sizeof( int() )` a legal expression?", particularly on the detail of how the grammar matching works when both of the above bulleted cases match.

Comment: Of course whatever `sizeof(int())` is *intended* to mean, there's certainly a clearer way to say it -- most likely `sizeof (int)`. (Yes, it's a language-lawyer question, so that's not a problem, I just thought I'd mention it.)

Comment: @skypjack please read first paragraph of my question

Comment: I've read it as a whole. I agree that none of them should be closed. I'm voting to reopen also this one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, `sizeof( int() )` is ill-formed because `int()` is taken to be a *type-id*. Specifically, it's a function type, and `sizeof` cannot be applied to a function type.

[[dcl.ambig.res]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.ambig.res#2):

> An ambiguity can arise from the similarity between a function-style
>   cast and a *type-id*. The resolution is that any construct that could
>   possibly be a *type-id* in its syntactic context shall be considered a
>   *type-id*.

with this exact example given:

> ```
> void foo(signed char a) {
>     sizeof(int());                // type-id (ill-formed)
>     sizeof(int(a));               // expression
>     sizeof(int(unsigned(a)));     // type-id (ill-formed)
> ```

Comment: This is a good answer -- except for the minor detail that it doesn't actually answer the question. You might want to mention that no, `sizeof( int() )` is not legal (because `sizeof` cannot be applied to a function type).

Comment: It's an interesting question & answer. The type int() can't be used with sizeof even though it can readily be assigned to an int(*)() without a cast (which presumably can be used with sizeof).

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou: `int(*)()` is a pointer type. Such an assignment is legal without a cast simply because an expression of function type is (in most contexts) implicitly converted to a pointer.