# Is a statement void(); legal and what is it actually?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have a little piece of code which has a statement `void();`

```
int main() 
{
   void( ); // 1: parses fine in GCC 5.4.0 -Wpedantic 
   // void;    // 2: error declaration does not declare anything
}
```

What is 1 `void()` exactly?

- An anonymous function declaration?
- A type declaration?
- An empty expression?

What makes 1 `void()` different from 2 `void;`?

I have read already:

1. [Is sizeof(void()) a legal expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39278200/417197) but there void() is considered a type in sizeof
2. [What does the void() in decltype(void()) mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39279074/417197) where it is considered in declspec.
3. And I read [Is void{} legal or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354065/is-void-legal-or-not?rq=1)

But I am curious if the loose statement void(); is different from one of those (and why of course)

Comment: I suspect void() is analogous to e.g. int pi = int(3.14);  ... except that instead of casting 3.14 to an int, you are casting an empty expression to type void (and then ignoring the result, which you have to do anyway since it's of type void).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279074/what-does-the-void-in-decltypevoid-mean-exactly I'm trying to find a better dupe

Comment: could be useful in templates so you don't have to specialize for void?

Comment: For those people pointing me to possible dupes: Most of the related questions are asked by user skypjack similar to the one I have put in the question. But I have not seen a case where the "loose statement" void(); is considered, but only in the context of decltype, sizeof, etc.

Comment: `void()` is often used as a type for a function which takes no arguments and returns no value.

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701321/construction-of-a-void-type

Comment: It's #3. Same category as `int;` failing but `int()` not.

Comment: @GillBates. Do you mean #3 as in it is a dupe of "Is void{} legal or not" or #3 as in the third bullet: it is an empty expression?

Comment: @Andre, It's an empty expression. `void()` is an expression with special meaning. It's also a function type in some contexts.

Comment: @andre Bullet point

Comment: @NathanOliver the answer by "chris" on your latest dupe is good, I'll go with that

Comment: @M.M Sounds good.

Comment: actually I changed my mind ... the difference between `void;` and `void();` needs some explanation , since they can both be *type-id*s , and the dupe doesn't cover that. Writing answer now

Answer (score 4):

`void;` is an error because there is no rule in the language grammar which matches that code. In particular, there is no rule *`type-id`* `;`,

However, the code `void()` matches two grammar rules:

1. *`type-id`* .
2. *`postfix-expression`*, with the sub-case being  *`simple-type-specifier`* `(` *`expression-list-opt`* `)`.

Now, the parser needs to match `void();` to a grammar rule. Even though `void()` matches *`type-id`*, as mentioned earlier there is no rule that would match *`type-id`* `;`. So the parser rejects the possible parsing of `void()` as *`type-id`* in this context, and tries the other possibility.

There **is** a series of rules defining that *`postfix-expression`* `;` makes a *statement*. So `void()` is unambiguously parsed as *postfix-expression* in this context.

As described by the other answers you linked already, the semantic meaning of this code as a *postfix-expression* is a prvalue of type `void`.

Related link: [Is `sizeof(int())` a legal expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281235/is-sizeofint-a-legal-expression)

Comment: [stmt.ambig] is the closer disambiguation rule here, I think. Of course, there's no ambiguity in the first place.

Comment: @T.C. I've edited, hopefully it is more accurate now. I'm not an expert in parsing, feel free to tidy anything up

Comment: And to be precise: This postfix-expression is an explicit cast? According to  "http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast", number four actually has specific explanation for void: *If new_type is (possibly cv-qualified) void, the expression is a void prvalue without a result object (since C++17).* I could not find a corresponding statement in the standard

Comment: @Andre the "result object" stuff is new in C++17, [basic.lval]/2 in N4618 has the text which your cppreference quote is based on.

Answer (score 0):

A `void` expression.

The compiler won't create any code for it, e.g.,

in VS

```
_asm
{
    nop;
}
void();
_asm
{
    nop;
}
```

produces this assembly:

```
_asm
{
    nop;
003017CE  nop  
}
void();
_asm
{
    nop;
003017CF  nop  
}
```