# What is the purpose of a void() expression?

Tags: c++, void, variable-declaration

You cannot declare a `void` variable:

```
void fn() {
    void a; // ill-formed
}
```

Yet this compiles:

```
void fn() {
    void(); // a void object?
}
```

What does `void()` mean? How is it useful? Why is `void a;` ill-formed, while `void()` OK?

```
void fn() {
    void a = void(); // ill-formed
}
```

Comment: Basically it means nothing or no type

Comment: I imagine this would be useful for templates

Comment: @sara You should take a closer look at the context here.

Comment: @SMcCrohan: it's not a duplicate of that. It only answers half of the question. If it is a void expression, then what its value? Why "void a;" is ill-formed, while "void()" is not?

Comment: I disagree this question is a duplicate of the suggested question.  The *answer* is the same ( specifically the C++ grammar declares that `void()` is an expression), but it is a very different usage.

Comment: Let me guess: `void();` is a function declaration like `void f();` where the variable name is optional.

Comment: The suggested answer discusses `decltype(void())` what is different from the simple use of void. Therefore the questions is not answered by that question.

Comment: @nwp : Your guess is wrong.  `int()` is an int value; `void()` is a void value (which is then discarded - you can't actually do anything else with a void value than discard it.)

Comment: @geza Which part isn't answered by the other question? How it is useful? Or why you can't have objects of void type? I voted to reopen in any case, if you think the questions aren't in the same spirit.

Comment: Apparently [you can do](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1c70d475a687449) `void f() { return void(); }` but not `void f() {return void{}; }`.

Comment: While `void()` is odd, it's fundamentally consistent with the fact that you can cast expressions to `void`, as in the statement `(void)5;` (which is sometimes done to explicitly signal that a return value is being ignored). In either case the expression produces a void value. You cannot declare a variable of type `void` because it is an incomplete type.

Comment: @miradulo: an example given for it usefulness. But note, that decltype is a C++11 feature. And I think that "void()" is older than that. What was its usefulness before C++11? Why the inconsistency there, that "T a = T();" is OK for all types (for which default constructor is available), except void? If "void()" is OK, why "void a" is not?

Comment: @nwp, interesting, why the difference is there.

Comment: There have been [attempts to make `void` a regular type](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0146r0.html). One can probably find official criticism of that proposal which might lead to insight into the reasoning.

Comment: @0x5f3759df: isn't it inconsistent? An expression results in a type, which is incomplete. How is it possible?

Comment: @geza The primary restriction placed on incomplete types is "Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type." This does not preclude expression of incomplete type. You can even dereference a pointer to an incomplete type (although it must be a pointer to object type, so void is excluded) and it is legal as long as an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion does not occur on the dereferenced object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a statement void(); legal and what is it actually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096571/is-a-statement-void-legal-and-what-is-it-actually)

Comment: @0x5f3759df: ah, that makes sense, thanks! Your comments actually answer the other part of my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
void();
```

creates a void value and then discards it.  (You can't actually do much with a void value other than discard it or return it.)

The [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)† says in 5.2.3 [expr.type.conv

> The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier for a non-array complete object
>   type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates a prvalue of the specified type, whose value is that
>   produced by value-initializing (8.5) an object of type T; no initialization is done for the void() case

Note that it explictaly calls out that `void()` is legal.

† My link is to N4296 which was the last public committee draft before C++14, however the various versions of the standard do not vary here.

---

**Edit**

Is it useful?  Explicitly like this? No.  I can't see a use for it.  It *is* however, useful in template functions which sometimes do something like:

```
template <typename T>
T foo() {
    if (prepare_for_for()) {
        return do_foo();
    } else {
        return T();
    }
}
```

And this will work, even for `T` == `void`.

Comment: This shows that it is legal (+1), but is it also useful?

Comment: @FabioTurati: unfortunately my question is actually two questions. This answer with 0x5f3759df comments under the question answers the second part.

Answer (score 3):

Syntactically `void()` is an explict type conversion written in *functional notation* (see 5.2.3).

Note that even in "classic" C (C89/90) explicit conversions to `void` were already allowed. Of course, in C one has to use "classic" C-style cast notation and supply an argument. Any expression can be cast to `void` in C, including expressions that are already `void`. This functionality migrated unchanged to *cast notation* of explicit type conversion in C++ (it is handled by `static_cast` branch of its functionality, i.e. you can `static_cast` to `void` in C++).

Taking the above into account, it is not surprising that conversion to `void` is also consistently supported by the alternative C++ cast syntax - *functional notation*. And once you understand that, it is no surprise that it was extended to support the "argument-less" version - `void()`.

The usefulness of this in C++ will include such contexts as generic functions

```
template <typename T>
T foo() {
  ...;
  return T(); // remains valid even when `T == void`
}
```

Note that in C++ it is perfectly legal to return `void` pseudo-values from `void` functions. The ability to create such `void()` pseudo-values eliminates the need to write dedicated `void` specializations for functions like the one above.

---

As a side note, `void()` stands for explicit type conversion only if the context forces it to be interpreted as an *expression*, as in your example. When context calls for a type  name (e.g. `int foo(void())` or `using T = void();`) it actually declares a nameless function that returns `void` and takes no arguments.

Comment: The no-so-easily-acceptable fact is that void is an incomplete type (I've just learned it), yet it can be used as a conversion target. How can one convert a value to an incomplete type? It's a little bit strange. But now I understand the behavior.

Comment: @geza: It is fair to say that `void` is *special* in this regard. In both C and C++ this conversion is given a separate description.