# Expression "void()" and its validity with ternary conditional

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find out whether the following code is valid (even if dubious in appearence)?

```
void hello(int, int) {}

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    
    a == b
        ? hello(a, b) 
        : void();

    return 0;
}
```

I have not found anything suggesting this would be invalid, and it compiles fine on clang and gcc. Questions I could find on SO were about `void()` in the context of decltype [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279074/what-does-the-void-in-decltypevoid-mean-exactly) and sizeof [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39278200/is-sizeofvoid-a-legal-expression). It seems to mean different things in different contexts.  If it is valid, I would like to know:

- What exactly does `void()` evaluate, if it does that at
  all, to? Can it be treated the same as an effectless void function
  call? Just `void`, in this use case, gives me a compiler
  error.
- Why is it not possible to simply omit one side of the ternary conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly does void() evaluate, if it does that at all, to?

Here, `void()` is in a context where the grammar expects an expression rather than a type. As such, it has the same meaning as in the linked question [What does the void() in decltype(void()) mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279074/what-does-the-void-in-decltypevoid-mean-exactly) i.e. it is a prvalue expression of type `void`.

> Why is it not possible to simply omit one side of the ternary conditional?

The grammar of the language does not allow that.

Answer (score 3):

`void()` is a valid expression which yields a *prvalue* of type `void`. It can therefore be used as a branch in the conditional operator.

The language does not allow you to omit one branch of the ternary conditional operator but if, for whatever reason, an `if` block is not to your liking, you could write

```
a == b && (hello(a, b), true);
```

where `hello(a, b)` will only be evaluated if `a` equals `b`.